# How to use a javascript component in vue.js with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a component defined in a project and want to expose like this, in order to use in another project:

> ```
> import ToastNotification from '../ToastNotification';
> import Api from './api';
>
> const VueToast = (Vue, options = {}) => {
>   const methods = Api(Vue, options);
>   Vue.$toast = methods;
>   Vue.prototype.$toast = methods;
> };
>
> ToastNotification.install = VueToast;
>
> export default ToastNotification;
> ```

In index.js I declare :

> ```
> import VueToast from './toast/js/index';
>
> Vue.use(VueToast);
> ```

And in another project I npm install this project as a library but this.$toast('message') is not recognized. It said that "Property '$toast' does not exist on type '' "

I mention that I managed to use inside the project, another class the 'this.$toast('')', but can't manage in another project.
The component is implemented in Vue.js using Javascript and I'm trying to use in another project that uses Vue.js that supports typescript.

I already tried to declare in my project in main.ts, but still does not work:

> import VueToast from'/src/components/toast/js/index';
>
> ```
> Vue.use(VueToast);
> ```

Do you have any idea about what I forgot to declare?

Answer (score 1):

To add `$toast` to the Vue component instance type, declare the following [type augmentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins) in a `.d.ts` file (e.g., in `src/shims-vue.d.ts`):

*Vue 2:*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $toast: (msg: string) => void;
  }
}

export {}
```

*Vue 3:*

```js
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $toast: (msg: string) => void;
  }
}

export {}
```